# Xposed framework on android L (5.0.2)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, xposed-framework

I would like install Xposed framework. My device is running Android L (5.0.2). The Xposed framework is compatible with android 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but the XPosed Framework is unable to work with ART (the default runtime on Android 5.0).
The fact that the code is compiled/optimized during installation blocks rerouting functions and injections done by XPosed.
XPosed will also refuse to install on Android 5 because it's not done, yet.
The developer said: "I am working on it, but it's far from being done. I'm not even able to install it. It may take more than 6 months to see an alpha version of XPosed on ART."